# MySQL syntax error near 'group = '1' WHERE id = 6' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql

I have a pretty simple task I want to perform, when I run the code one way it's fine, if I run it another way *Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception'...*

**Works**

```
if (Input::get('userid')) {

    $user_id = Input::get('userid');

    $user->find($user_id);

    $name = $user->data()->first_name;


    if ($user->data()->active == 1) {

        $user->update(array(
            'active' => 0
        ));

        Session::flash('userboard', $name.' Deactivated');
        Redirect::to('admin.php');

    } else {

        $user->update(array(
            'active' => 1
        ));

        Session::flash('userboard', $name.' Activated');
        Redirect::to('admin.php');

    }

}
```

**Doesn't Work**

```
if (Input::get('adminid')) {

    $user_id = Input::get('adminid');

    $user->find($user_id);

    $name = $user->data()->first_name;

    if ($user->data()->active == 1) {

        $user->update(array(
            'group' => 1
        ));

        Session::flash('userboard', $name.' Deactivated');
        Redirect::to('admin.php');

    } else {

        $user->update(array(
            'group' => 2
        ));

        Session::flash('userboard', $name.' Activated');
        Redirect::to('admin.php');

    }

}
```

No matter which way I change it around I can't update the group. They are both int(11) in MySQL. I'm almost wondering if I need to delete the column and re add it? This group value is used for setting user permissions if that's of any help.

---

**PDO errorInfo**

> Array (  [0] => 42000  [1] => 1064  [2] => You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'group = '1' WHERE id = 6' at
>   line 1  )

Comment: This is why you need to retrieve error messages.

Comment: did you get a valid value for `Input::get('adminid')`?

Comment: Like this @Devon?

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'There was a problem updating your account' in /classes/User.php:85 Stack trace: #0 /admin.php(68): User->update(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /classes/User.php on line 85

Comment: @Sam, that isn't a very good error message.  You really need the MySQL related error message.  I'm not sure what framework you are using but there must be a way to retrieve it.

Comment: Does this help @Devon?

PDO::errorInfo(): Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group = '1' WHERE id = 6' at line 1 )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your framework, or class, isn't putting ticks around the column.  Group is a reserved keyword in MySQL (and probably every DBMS), so the column must be quoted with backticks: `group`

Comment: Thanks @Devon. Whereabouts? The actual mysql column or my code that I showed you above?

Comment: The query that is being executed as a result of `$user->update()`

Comment: Got it, all fixed. Thank you so much! Between that and Chrome's Favicon bug with CSRF I've been having an interesting night!